# Reading attached files in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So i am reading the attached files on my client side using the **req.body** object and i have been trying to use the following code to get the attached files byte data

```
function readFiles(files){
    readMultipleFiles(files, function(err, bufs){
        if(err){
            throw err;
        }else{
            console.log(bufs);
        }
    });
}

var files = req.body.uploadedImages;
```

The readMultipleFiles is an npm module https://www.npmjs.com/package/read-multiple-files

I keep getting the following error
**Error: ENOENT, open 'test1.png'
    at Error (native)**

Could someone point out what is the exact way to read files from client side and get the byte data pertaining that specific file?

**Edit**
I am trying to achieve something along these lines

```
{"imageFileName":"test.png","imageData":[71,73,70,56,57,97,-60,0,-60,0,-13,0,0,-‌​116,-116,......]}
```

How do i go about getting the "imageData"?

Comment: @laggingreflex from the attached files i want to byte into an array, i am trying something along these lines {"imageFileName":"test.png","imageData":[71,73,70,56,57,97,-60,0,-60,0,-13,0,0,-116,-116,......]}, how would i go about getting the imageData

Comment: The image data will be in the form of a stream-buffer.

Comment: [Checkout some of these links that explain how file uploads work in detail.](http://google.com/search?q=node+file+uploads)

Comment: @Bwaxxlo could you please expand on your answer a bit

Comment: @Raj Node handles data as streams. You have a read/write stream. With your image data, you'll need to pipe it from a read stream to a write stream. How do you do so? Here's a sample file upload logic: http://www.componentix.com/blog/9/file-uploads-using-nodejs-now-for-real